long durations between connectEnd and requestStart
I was looking into a performance issue and found sometimes there are long durations (up to several seconds) between connectEnd and requestStart.
"connectStart":5465.4000000059605
"connectEnd":5465.4000000059605
"secureConnectionStart":5465.4000000059605
"requestStart":9798

Are there any ideas what is happening between the gap?
